# Update query update not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, arrays

I am doing Add, Update and Delete in Php.

Everything is working fine but My Update query is not working.

Can I know, where i am going wrong in Update query?

Here is my update.php file code..

```html
<?php

include('connection.php'); 

$ID = $_REQUEST['Student_Id'];

$result = mysql_query("select* from tblstudent where Student_Id='".$ID."'");

while($oldvalue=  mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
    $oldname=$oldvalue['Student_Name'];
    $oldgender=$oldvalue['Gender'];
    $olddob=$oldvalue['DOB'];
    $oldaddress=$oldvalue['Address'];
    $oldmobileno=$oldvalue['Phone'];
    $olddivision=$oldvalue['Division'];
    $oldclass=$oldvalue['Class'];
    $oldemail=$oldvalue['Email_Id'];

}

if(isset ($_POST['submit']))
{

    $update = $_POST['submit'];

        if($update)
        {
            $newname=$_POST['Student_Name'];
            $newgender=$_POST['Gender'];
            $newdob=$_POST['DOB'];
            $newaddress=$_POST['Address'];
            $newmobileno=$_POST['Phone'];
            $newdivision=$_POST['Division'];
            $newclass=$_POST['Class'];
            $newemail=$_POST['Email_Id'];
    
          /* UPDATE QUERY */                        

           mysql_query("UPDATE tblstuent SET Student_Name='$newname', Gender='$newgender', DOB='$newdob', Address='$newaddress', Phone='$newmobileno', Division='$newdivision', Class='$newclass', Email_Id='$newemail'
                   WHERE id='$ID'");
            
            header('location:index.php');
        }
}

?>

<body>
         <form action="update.php" method="post">
                
                <fieldset>
                
                    <legend>Personal Information</legend><br/>   
                    
                    <div class="studentname"><label>Student Name :</label><input type="text" name="newstudentname" id="studentnameId" value="<?php echo $oldname ?>" placeholder="Enter Name" size="30px" /></div><br/>
                    
                    <div class="gender">
           
                         <label>Gender :</label>
                         
                         <input type="radio" name="type" value="Male" <?php echo ($oldgender == 'Male') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />  Male
                         <input type="radio" name="type" value="Female" <?php echo ($oldgender == 'Female') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>/> Female<br />

                    </div> <br/>
                    
                    <div class="dob"><label>Date of Birth :</label><input type="text" name="dob" id="dobId" value="<?php echo $olddob ?>" placeholder="Enter DOB format Year-Month-DaY" size="30px" /></div><br/>
                    
                    <div class="address"><label class="addresschild">Address : </label><textarea rows="4" cols="21" name="address" id="addressId" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Address"><?php echo $oldaddress ?></textarea></div><br/>

                    <div class="mobileno"><label>Parent's Mobile No : </label><input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobilenoId" value="<?php echo $oldmobileno ?>" placeholder="Enter Parent's Mobile No" size="30px" /></div><br/>
                    
                    <div class="selectdivision">
                        
                        <label>Divison :</label>

                        <select id="divisiondropdownId" name="divisiondropdown">
                            <option value="0">Select Division</option>
                            <option value="A"<?php if($olddivision=="A") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >A</option>
                            <option value="B"<?php if($olddivision=="B") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >B</option>
                            <option value="C"<?php if($olddivision=="C") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >C</option>
                        </select>
                        
                    </div><br/>
                    
                    <div class="selectclass">
                        
                        <label>Class :</label>
                        
                        <select id="classdropdownId" name="classdropdown">
                        
                            <option value="0">Select Class</option>
                            <option value="First"<?php if($oldclass=="First") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>First</option>
                            <option value="Second"<?php if($oldclass=="Second") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Second</option>
                            <option value="Third"<?php if($oldclass=="Third") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Third</option>
                            <option value="Fourth"<?php if($oldclass=="Fourth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Fourth</option>
                            <option value="Fifth"<?php if($oldclass=="Fifth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Fifth</option>
                            <option value="Sixth"<?php if($oldclass=="Sixth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Sixth</option>
                            <option value="Seventh"<?php if($oldclass=="Seventh") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Seventh</option>
                            <option value="Eighth"<?php if($oldclass=="Eighth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Eighth</option>
                            <option value="Nineth"<?php if($oldclass=="Nineth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Nineth</option>
                            <option value="Tenth"<?php if($oldclass=="Tenth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Tenth</option>
                        
                        </select>
                        
                    </div><br/>
                    
                    
                    <div class="emailid"><label>Email-Id : </label><input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailId" value="<?php echo $oldemail ?>" placeholder="Enter your Email-id" size="30px" /></div><br/>
                   
                    
                    <div id="submit1">
                        
                        <input class="btnsubmit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                        
                        <input class="btnreset" type="reset" name="reset" id="submit" value="Reset" />
                    
                    </div><br/>

                </fieldset>

            </form>
</body>
```

Thank you

Rahul Barge

Comment: What error do you get?(For error reporting use: `<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>`) Also put ` around your column names in the update statement

Comment: check your query again, it has a typo `tblstuent`, it should be `tblstudent`

Comment: @Yohanes Khosiawan :- thank you, but now also update query is not working.

Comment: @Rizier123 :- I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Friends thank you,

All your answers helped me to solve problem.

I learn alot from you all.

Finally i solved above problem doing some changes in update.php file code..

Here is my new code

```html
<?php

include('connection.php'); 

if(isset ($_REQUEST['Student_Id']))
{
    $id = $_REQUEST['Student_Id'];
    
    $result = mysql_query("select* from tblstudent where Student_Id ='".$id."'");
    
    while($oldvalue=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $oldid = $oldvalue['Student_Id'];
    $oldname=$oldvalue['Student_Name'];
    $oldgender=$oldvalue['Gender'];
    $olddob=$oldvalue['DOB'];
    $oldaddress=$oldvalue['Address'];
    $oldmobileno=$oldvalue['Phone'];
    $olddivision=$oldvalue['Division'];
    $oldclass=$oldvalue['Class'];
    $oldemail=$oldvalue['Email_Id'];

    }   
}

if(isset ($_POST['newname']))
{

            $newname =$_POST['newname'];
            
            $newid =$_POST['newid'];
            
            $newgender =$_POST['newgender'];
            
            $newdob = $_POST['newdob'];
            
            $newaddress = $_POST['newaddress'];
            
            $newphone = $_POST['newphone'];
            
            $newdivision = $_POST['newdivision'];
            
            $newclass = $_POST['newclass'];
            
            $newemailid = $_POST['newemailid'];
            
            $sql= "UPDATE tblstudent SET Student_Name='$newname', Gender='$newgender', DOB='$newdob', Address='$newaddress', Phone='$newphone', Division='$newdivision', Class='$newclass', Email_Id='$newemailid' WHERE Student_Id='$newid'";
            
            $result= mysql_query($sql);
            
            header('location:index.php');

}

?>



<body>
         <form action="update.php" method="post">
                
                <fieldset>
                
                    <legend>Personal Information</legend><br/>
                    
                    <div class="studentname"><label>Student Name :</label><input type="text" name="newname" id="studentnameId" value="<?php echo $oldname ?>" placeholder="Enter First & Last Name" size="30px" /></div><br/>
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="newid" value="<?php echo $oldid ?>"/>
                    
                    <div class="gender">
           
                         <label>Gender :</label>
                         
                         <input type="radio" name="newgender" value="Male" <?php echo ($oldgender == 'Male') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />  Male
                         <input type="radio" name="newgender" value="Female" <?php echo ($oldgender == 'Female') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>/> Female<br />


                    </div> <br/>
                    
                    <div class="dob"><label>Date of Birth :</label><input type="text" name="newdob" id="dobId" value="<?php echo $olddob ?>" placeholder="Enter DOB format Year-Month-DaY" size="30px" /></div><br/>
                    
                    <div class="address"><label class="addresschild">Address : </label><textarea rows="4" cols="21" name="newaddress" id="addressId" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Address"><?php echo $oldaddress ?></textarea></div><br/>

                    <div class="mobileno"><label>Parent's Mobile No : </label><input type="text" name="newphone" id="mobilenoId" value="<?php echo $oldmobileno ?>" placeholder="Enter Parent's Mobile No" size="30px" /></div><br/>
                    
                    <div class="selectdivision">
                        
                        <label>Divison :</label>

                        <select id="divisiondropdownId" name="newdivision">
                            <option value="0">Select Division</option>
                            <option value="A"<?php if($olddivision=="A") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >A</option>
                            <option value="B"<?php if($olddivision=="B") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >B</option>
                            <option value="C"<?php if($olddivision=="C") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >C</option>
                        </select>
                        
                        
                        
                    </div><br/>
                    
                    <div class="selectclass">
                        
                        <label>Class :</label>
                        
                        <select id="classdropdownId" name="newclass">
                        
                            <option value="0">Select Class</option>
                            <option value="First"<?php if($oldclass=="First") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>First</option>
                            <option value="Second"<?php if($oldclass=="Second") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Second</option>
                            <option value="Third"<?php if($oldclass=="Third") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Third</option>
                            <option value="Fourth"<?php if($oldclass=="Fourth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Fourth</option>
                            <option value="Fifth"<?php if($oldclass=="Fifth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Fifth</option>
                            <option value="Sixth"<?php if($oldclass=="Sixth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Sixth</option>
                            <option value="Seventh"<?php if($oldclass=="Seventh") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Seventh</option>
                            <option value="Eighth"<?php if($oldclass=="Eighth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Eighth</option>
                            <option value="Nineth"<?php if($oldclass=="Nineth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Nineth</option>
                            <option value="Tenth"<?php if($oldclass=="Tenth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Tenth</option>
                        
                        </select>
                        
                    </div><br/>
                    
                    
                    <div class="emailid"><label>Email-Id : </label><input type="text" name="newemailid" id="emailId" value="<?php echo $oldemail ?>" placeholder="Enter your Email-id" size="30px" /></div><br/>
                   
                    
                    <div id="submit1">
                        
                        <input class="btnsubmit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                        
                        <input class="btnreset" type="reset" name="reset" id="submit" value="Reset" />
                    
                    </div><br/>

                </fieldset>

            </form>
</body>
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have an example with PDO and prepared statements for you. Also if I was you I would start learning PDO with prepared statements. MySQL is deprecated and can get you into trouble.

This example is using Student_Id as auto increment and primary

SelectStudentPage.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE> 
    <html>

    <head>

    <title>Students</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "Studentsdb";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblstudent ");
    $stmt->execute();

 ?>

    <?php //start of the while loop ?>
    <?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>

 <table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 1080px;">

    <br>
    <tr> 
        <th style="width:125px">STUDENT ID</th>
        <th style="width:125px">STUDENT NAME</th>
        <th style="width:100px">GENDER</th>
        <th style="width:100px">DOB</th>
        <th style="width:250px">ADDRESS</th>
        <th style="width:100px">PHONE</th>
        <th style="width:100px">DIVISION</th>
        <th style="width:100px">CLASS</th>
        <th style="width:250px">EMAIL ID</th>

    </tr>
    <tr style="width:25px">
    <?php $id = $row['Student_Id'];?>
    <?php echo  "<td> <a href='StudentUpdateForm.php?Student_Id=$id'>$id</a></td>"?>
        <td><?php echo $row['Student_Name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Gender']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['DOB']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Address']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Division']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Class']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Email_Id']; ?></td>

    </tr>

    </table>

      <?php } //end of the while loop?>
    </body>

</html>
```

StudentUpdateForm.php

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "Studentsdb";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $id=$_GET['Student_Id'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblstudent Where Student_Id=:Student_Id");
    $result->bindParam(':Student_Id', $id);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Update Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="UpdateProcess.php" method="post">
        <legend>Personal Information</legend><br>
            <div>
            <label>Student Id :<label><input name="Student_Id" type="text" value=
            "<?php print($row['Student_Id']) ?>">
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <label>Student Name :</label><input name="Student_Name" type="text" value=
            "<?php print($row['Student_Name']) ?>">
        </div><br>

        <div>
            <label>Gender :</label>
            <select name ="Gender" style="width: 149px" >
                <option value <?php if ($row['Gender']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Male">Male</option>
                <option value <?php if ($row['Gender']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div><br>

        <div>
            <label>Date of Birth :</label><input name="DOB" type="text" value=
            "<?php print($row['DOB']) ?>">
        </div><br>

        <div>
            <label>Address :</label><textarea name="Address"><?php echo $row['Address']; ?></textarea><br>
        </div><br>

        <div>
            <label>parents mobile no:</label><input name="Phone" type="text"value=
            "<?php print($row['Phone']) ?>">
        </div><br>

        <div>
            <label>Divison :</label><br>
            <select name ="Division" style="width: 149px" >
                <option value <?php if ($row['Division']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="A">A</option>
                <option value <?php if ($row['Division']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="B">B</option>
                <option value <?php if ($row['Division']==3){ print('selected');}  ?> ="C">C</option>
        </select>
        </div><br>

        <div>
            <label>Class :</label><br>
             <select name ="Class" style="width: 149px" >
                <option value <?php if ($row['Class']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="First">First</option>
                <option value <?php if ($row['Class']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Second">Second</option>
                <option value <?php if ($row['Class']==3){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Third">Third</option>
            </select>
        </div><br>

        <div>
            <label>Email id :</label><input name="Email_Id" type="text" value=
            "<?php print($row['Email_Id']) ?>">
        </div><br>

        <div id="submit1">
            <input class="btnsubmit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit"
            value="Update"> <input class="btnreset" id="submit" name="reset"
            type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div><br>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

UpdateProcess.php

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "Studentsdb";
try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$sql = 'UPDATE tblstudent SET Student_Id=:Student_Id, Student_Name=:Student_Name, Gender=:Gender, DOB=:DOB, Address=:Address, Phone=:Phone, Division=:Division, Class=:Class, Email_Id=:Email_Id WHERE Student_Id=:Student_Id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(':Student_Id', $_POST['Student_Id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':Student_Name', $_POST['Student_Name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':Gender', $_POST['Gender'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':DOB', $_POST['DOB'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':Address', $_POST['Address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':Phone', $_POST['Phone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':Division', $_POST['Division'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':Class', $_POST['Class'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':Email_Id', $_POST['Email_Id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->rowCount()  .  " record Updated successfully.";
}catch(PDOException $exception){ 
            echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }   
echo "<a href=http://localhost/students/SelectStudentPage.php>Go to Grid view Results page</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

along with having typo,you used

```
 $ID = $_REQUEST['Student_Id'];
```

in your code i dont found any element with id 'Student_Id' in your form, so there will be no value in $ID, and no update will be done.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not commenting. I don't have 50 points yet.

I saw few errors in your query.

1. table name. in select query it's `tblstudent` and in update query its `tblstuent`
2. `'$newname'` is better to concatinate like this. `'".$newname."'`. and this should do for all variables.
3. No `STUDENT_ID` in your code. So add it as a hidden field.
4. Make sure column names spelled in the same way as it is in the table. simple/capital and spellings.

Answer (score 1):

if you are updating same table than you should pass **Student_Id**  instead of **id** in below query,

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE tblstuent SET Student_Name='$newname', Gender='$newgender', DOB='$newdob', Address='$newaddress', Phone='$newmobileno', Division='$newdivision', Class='$newclass', Email_Id='$newemail'
                   WHERE id='$ID'");
```

or You had set wrong table name **tblstuent** , it should be **tblstudent** if you are updating same table.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Student_Name='$newname', 

put $newname in double quotes like this.

Student_Name="$newname",
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query check data type of all column then as data type you need to set column value with quotes if datatype like string,date. otherwise not need to set quotes for good practice. and in your update query you write table name wrong so first update this. after check

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id' " ;

   while($oldvalue=  mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
    $oldname=$oldvalue['Student_Name'];
    $oldgender=$oldvalue['Gender'];
    $olddob=$oldvalue['DOB'];
    $oldaddress=$oldvalue['Address'];
    $oldmobileno=$oldvalue['Phone'];
    $olddivision=$oldvalue['Division'];
    $oldclass=$oldvalue['Class'];
    $oldemail=$oldvalue['Email_Id'];

}



    if(mysql_query("DESCRIBE `table`")) {

                $sql = "UPDATE table SET ";
                $sql.= " Student_Name = '$oldname', Gender = '$oldgender',.... ";
                $sql.= " WHERE id = '$id' ";

        if(mysql_query($sql)){
           echo 'Good';
        }    
        else 
        {
        echo 'Bad';
        }
    }
```

Try something like this ;)